# Prevent Firefox from ignoring javascript when restoring tabs on restart

Tags: jquery, firefox

My page contains the code line

```
<body onload="$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');">
```

This code is executed properly in Firefox and MSIE when a tab is refreshed or reloaded. Both browsers are set to restore tabs from the previous session on restart. When MSIE is restarted, the tabs are restored and apparently refreshed, because checkboxes which were checked in the previous session are now unchecked. But when Firefox is restarted, the tabs are restored but apparently not refreshed, as the checked checkboxes from the earlier session are not cleared.

Can I add code which will force Firefox to allow the onload event to run in restored tabs after a browser restart, or can this behavior only be changed by the user (or not at all)?

Comment: I believe this behaviour is controlled in the browser at a lower level than JS has access to, so there's not much you can do to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rory. In the absence of any other reaction, I shall pursue this on the Mozilla bug/feature page.